# SQL: SUM on MAX of a Grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, max

```
GroupName         Name         BucketID AddInd
Test Group 2      Males 0-9    1        12
Test Group 2      Males 10-17  2        12
Test Group 2      Males 18-24  3         1
Test Group 2      Males 18-24  3         4
Test Group 2      Males 25+    4         2
Test Group 3      Males 10-17  2         3
Test Group 3      Males 18-24  3         4
Test Group 3      Males 25+    4         6
Test Youth Group  Males 10-17  2         2
Test Youth Group  Males 18-24  3        12
Test Youth Group  Males 25+    4        NULL
```

So, out of this data (example), I need to pull the MAX(AddInd) of a Name WITHIN each group and then SUM each of those into the result.

For example: Test Group 2 has TWO Males 18-24, so I only want the MAX one (4)

```
Test Group 2      Males 18-24  3         1
Test Group 2      Males 18-24  3         4
```

and then need to SUM that and all other Males 18-24 in OTHER Groups, e.g.

```
Test Youth Group  Males 18-24  3        12
Test Group 3      Males 18-24  3         4
```

So, my answer would need to be the SUM of 4+12+4.

I can't figure out the query. Any ideas?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Seems to be a good use for Over Order/partition by syntax in combination with group by and max()

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you can just use an inline view to get what you want.

```
SELECT name, 
       Sum (max_addind) 
FROM   (SELECT groupname, 
               name, 
               Max(addind) max_AddInd 
        FROM   groups 
        GROUP  BY groupname, 
                  name) AS t 
GROUP  BY name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62e58/2)

Which produces this output

```
|        NAME |          |
--------------------------
|   Males 0-9 |       12 |
| Males 10-17 |       17 |
| Males 18-24 |       20 |
|   Males 25+ |        8 |
```